# Properties backing field - What is it good for?

Tags: c#

On one hand, I know that the advisable usage of Properties is to have a backing field, like in the following example:

```
    private int m_Capacity;

    public int Capacity
    {
        get { return m_Capacity > 0 ? m_Capacity : -666; }
        set { m_Capacity = value; }
    }
```

On the other hand, what benefit do I get from using the above example over discarding the field and using only the property for all purposes, like in the following example:

```
    public int Capacity
    {
        get { return Capacity > 0 ? Capacity : -666; }
        set { Capacity = value; }
    }
```

What is good about using a backing field for regular (non-auto-implemented) properties?

Comment: Don't you find that your second example results in StackOverflowExceptions? Have you written it correctly? You're currently referencing the property from within the property itself.

Comment: You're all correct. I didn't think this through nor did I run the code.

Comment: @Alex Humphrey: .. from within the property itself within the property itself within the property itself..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you do this:

```
public int Capacity 
{ 
    get { return Capacity > 0 ? Capacity : -666; } 
    set { Capacity = value; } 
}
```

then your code will have an infinite recursion. It will never work. That's because the getter for Capacity is referencing itself. Same thing goes for the setter.

Unless you are using automatic properties, you need a backing field

Comment: It's a shame backing fields can't be automatic; that would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation. If this is true, is it safe to say that properties without any logic within a getter / setter are best left as auto implemented properties? Perhaps with a "private setter" to encapsulate it as well?

Answer (score 11):

The explicit private memberid is useful if you ever need to access the actual value of m_Capacity, rather than the 'managed' value you get from the Capacity property,

EDIT: The other posts correctly point out the syntax error. I should have mentioned it too, but I ignored it and just tried to answer his question, which seemed to be about automatic properties

Comment: Or if you need to change the way that Capacity is calculated. Properties with backing private variables are a very easy way of decoupling.

Comment: This should be voted the answer. The current accepted answer just states that you need a property but not *why* it's needed, which would answer OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget that Properties are simply shorthand syntax for generating getter and setter methods. They look like fields, but they are not.

Comment: also called "syntax sugar".

Answer (score 5):

Backing fields support the concept of encapsulation.

Encapsulation allows you to later change the implementation details of the class without changing its interface.

This means that having a backing field with getters and setters instead of having a public class member will make your code more robust and/or readable for future developers or your future self.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly because you will get a StackOverflow.

Comment: Indeed.  This, specifically, causes most SOs that I remember seeing recently in .Net code.  I wonder if a compilation warning would be appropriate; does this usage ever make sense?

Comment: Is it Resharper which puts a little symbol in the left margin when a call is recursive?   I always see it, but I'm never sure whether things like that are R# or VS.

Comment: Probably Resharper; i've never seen anything like that in a stock VS.