# Calling property methods from within a structure

Tags: c#, struct, structure

I have a structure with a bunch of properties. All properties have a corresponding method called someMethod(). I am trying to call the method for each property that is in the struct. I need to be able to do this without anything except the struct. Is this even possible?

```
public class someStruct()
{
    public int prop1{get, set}
    public int prop2{get, set}
    public int prop3{get, set}
}
```

This obviously isn't my code, but gets the point across. Assume each prop has an add(). I could normally do:

```
someStruct example = new someStruct();
example.prop1.add();
example.prop2.add();
example.prop3.add();
```

But I need to have a method where I can pass in example and it will call add() for each property. End goal is to have a method called callAdds:

```
callAdds(example);
```

Comment: Why do you have those methods?  Why are you not just accessing the properties directly?

Comment: What do these methods do, and how are they associated with the property? Could you show some code?

Comment: That is not an option at the moment. I have many different structures that need the same thing done.

Comment: I'm sure its possible, but a practical example is impossible without an example for reference.

Comment: Indeed - with a short but complete example I'm sure it'll be fairly simple...

Comment: Yes, it is possible using reflection.

Comment: I added some code, hopefully I can figure this out.

Comment: See full get/set syntax on following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c

Answer (score -1):

```
try use
    //if this is the only format of date and time then you can use,
    Regex stringDatePattern=new Regex("*[0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9[0-9][0-9]]*");
    return stringDatePattern.IsMatch(TextBox.Text);
    //Split the string
    Regex.Split Method (String, String, RegexOptions);
```

Comment: I think you meant to post this on a different question. It has nothing to do with what is being asked.