# Multiply Value in Set Backing Field in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multiplication, backing-field

I'm looking to multiply a value in the `set` backing field in C# (for an ASP.NET MVC application). I'm doing this to avoid [issues with dividing floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and therefore the properties are integers that require to be multiplied and divided for the sake of appearance and then stored as decimals.

Following the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c), I'm trying to use the backing fields to complete these operation on a property like so:

```
public decimal SomeDecimal
{
    get
    {
        return this.SomeDecimal / 100;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SomeDecimal = this.SomeDecimal * 100;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Could anyone explain the proper way to multiply and divide the number without doing so in the view / controller.

Comment: For starters you need a backing field. Otherwise you have an infinite loop that will give you a stack overflow the first time you try to get `SomeDecimal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backing field is a separate member from your property. It's typically declared as private, of the same type as the property, and with the same name but in camelCase or with an underscore:

```
private decimal someDecimal;
```

Then, your property is defined to read from and write to this field. In case of the setter, you use the keyword `value` to get the value that was assigned to the property:

```
public decimal SomeDecimal
{
    get
    {
        return this.someDecimal / 100;
    }
    set
    {
        this.someDecimal = value * 100;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Your concern about loss of accuracy from floating-point arithmetic might be inapplicable in this case. Unlike `float` and `double`, which are stored as base-2 representations, `decimal` is stored in base 10. There should never be any loss of accuracy if you're performing simple arithmetic calculations (such as summations) on reasonable monetary values with two decimal places – the type was designed for that purpose.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Thanks for your explanation! (Will accept once time limit has gone)

Comment: Thanks for the info around floating points. The issue I have in this case is that the values are interpreted by javascript client-side for a calculator style app (which doesn't like the decimals!)

Answer (score 2):

When you reference this.SomeDecimal within the getter and setter for SomeDecimal you are creating an infinite recursion.

You want to create a private field that stores the true value, then use the property to get and set it according to your scheme for multiplying/dividing it.

```
private decimal _someDecimal;
public decimal SomeDecimal
{
    get
    {
        return _someDecimal / 100;
    }
    set
    {
        _someDecimal = value * 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!