# Singleton class crash when set an attribut with no exception

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, singleton

I have an strange comportement with my singleton class.

```
public class HttpCommunicator{
    public const int TYPEJSON = 1;

    private static HttpCommunicator;
    private bool TypeIsInit = false;

    public static HttpCommunicator Instance {
        get{
            if( instance == null ){
                instance = new HttpCommunication();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private HttpCommunicator(){}

    public int RequestType {get {return RequestType;} set{ this.RequestType = value; TypeIsInit = true;}
}
```

And later in another class i call this

```
HttpComminicator.Instance.RequestType = HttpCommunicator.TYPEJSON;
```

My app get stuck/freeze and my debugger don't show me any error. But if I change the get;set; method for this attribut to:

```
public int GetRequestType(){
    return RequestType;
}

public void SetRequestType(int value){
    RequestType = value;
    TypeIsInit = true;
}
```

everything works like a charm.

Anybody can explain me why I get this?

Comment: What is the problem if it works like a charm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your property:

```
public int RequestType
{
   get { return RequestType; }
   set { this.RequestType = value; TypeIsInit = true; }
}
```

You have a bunch of problems here.

What happens when you get that property?
`RequestType.get` is going to execute, which in turn is going to `return RequestType;`. To return `RequestType` you must read `RequestType`, which will trigger `RequestType.get` and the loop will go on and on and on and on.

My point is that you're trying to return a property by returning said property, which will probably end up causing a `StackOverflowException`.

The same can be said about your `set` accessor.

To fix this, have private fields behind the scenes:

```
private int _requestType;
public int RequestType
{
     get { return _requestType; }
     set { _requestType = value; TypeIsInit = true; }
}
```

Comment: You are right, i made a mistake when i wrote this code, i just made a search about your write and found the correct answer in this post [5096926](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c)

Comment: I notice that i use often the get; set; syntax and I never met this problem since today.

I write this

    public string Something {get; set;}

and later in code call Something = "Hello"
and to get just Log.I('',Something);

Comment: @Leze `public string Something { get; set; }` is very different from `public string Something { get { return Something; } set { Something = value; } }`

Comment: I get it now, I have never seen that before. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Leze No problem! Always glad to help!