# Using or not get and set methods in C# classes

Tags: c#, class, properties

In c# when I always heard that is a good practice when creating a property for a class to include the get e set functions. For example:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I think the reason to be a good practice is that if I want to change the behaviour I do not need to change the public interface of my class. Example:

```
public int Id 
{ 
   get; 
   set
   {
      if (value < 0)
         value = 0;
   }
}
```

My question is, if I declare my property without the get and set methods I will not get the same effect? If I declare my property like this:

```
public int Count;
```

Can I change is behaviour without change the public interface?
If I get the same effect then what’s the point of creating the get and set methods by default if in 90% of the time we don’t need them?

Comment: `public int Count;` is not a property, but a field.

Comment: You are declaring [field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/1997232).

Comment: Creating public fields removes any ability you have to validate input. So some external class can change count and the internal class has no way to know whether the count is valid or not. Using the properties lets you do validation.

Comment: See this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx

Comment: Whereas `public int Count { get; set; }` is an automatically-implemented property... and your initial piece of code is simply invalid.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate, not because it is a perfect match to your question, but your question relies on a misunderstanding of properties and fields.

Comment: See this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- I'm trying to find the SO resource that tells you when you can close questions without votes from others.  What rep do you earn that at?

Comment: If you are a gold tag badge holder on the specific tag you can close as duplicate without others.

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- Ahh, good to know, thanks.

Comment: @roryap http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/245360