# c# convert existing class to use properties correctly

Tags: c#, properties, containers

I have the following classes:

```
class Given
{
    public string text = "";
    public List<StartCondition> start_conditions = new List<StartCondition>();
};

class StartCondition
{
    public int index = 0;
    public string device = "unknown";
    public string state = "disconnected";
    public bool isPass = false;
};
```

I want to convert them into c# properties (using get; and set;)

Looking at this question: [what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c), it seems I can make a property nice and easy like this:

```
class Given
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<StartCondition> start_conditions { get; set; }
};

class StartCondition
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public bool isPass { get; set; }
};
```

But now I don't know how I should add my initialisations, because I want the same start values as I had before, or for the List container I want it to be new'ed.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you on c# 6?  Because if so, just add `{ get; set; } = 0`, etc.  Otherwise, just initialize in the constructor.

Comment: You can also add constructors to the classes to and make them set those parameters any time the class is instantiated.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks very much - seems obvious now :o  ... I have C#2015, not sure what C# 6 is?

Comment: @B.Rickman Also a good point!, for some reason I was not sure if the name of the "private" (hidden?) variable is the same as the "public" one

Comment: @code_fodder, if you're on VS2015, then you have access to C# 6 features.

Comment: @KirkWoll, ah ok thanks!... I guess this is a standards version, like C++11 / C++14?

Comment: Yeah, basically. Typically new versions of VS come with a new version of C#, though they are not strictly correlated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to have auto property initializers is included since C# 6.0. The syntax is:

```
public int X { get; set; } = x; // C# 6 or higher
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is C# 2015 > C#6?  ... I assume it is

Answer (score 4):

Use a constructor. So your class would look like this:

```
public class StartCondition
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public bool isPass { get; set; }

   // This is the constructor - notice the method name is the same as your class name
   public StartCondition(){
      // initialize everything here
      index = 0;
      device = "unknown";
      state = "disconnected";
      isPass = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i would do, as i said in the comments of the question. =]

Comment: Same here - and yes, i was typing as you added a comment. Feel free to add an answer if you prefer.....

Comment: Nope, you beat me to it! i upvoted your answer as i think its the best.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Constructor to start your class instance with the default values

```
class Given
{
    public Given(){
        this.text = "";
        start_conditions = new List<StartCondition>();
    }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<StartCondition> start_conditions { get; set; }
};

class StartCondition
{
    public StartCondition(){
        this.index = 0;
        this.device = "unknown";
        this.state = "disconnected";
        this.isPass = false;
    }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public bool isPass { get; set; }
};
```

Now you can create your instances with the default values by using `StartCondition A = new StartCondition();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using C# 6+ (or even if you are), you can explicitly declare your backing variables for properties:

```
public class Given
{
    private string _text = string.Empty;
    private List<StartCondition> _start_conditions = new List<StartCondition>();

    public string text { get{ return _text; } set{ _text = value; } }
    public List<StartCondition> start_conditions { get{ return _start_conditions; } set{ _start_conditions = value; } }
}
```

This allows you to set your initializations as before.