# C# property set if

Tags: c#, properties, setter

Can I make a property in c# class that has no field, but I still can check the value and set it only if match?

I mean something like this:

```
public int Num
{
    get;
    set if value > 0 && value < 100;
}
```

I know that I can do this:

```
private int num;
public int Num
{
    get
    {
        return num;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 0 && value < 100)
            num = value;
    }
}
```

But I want to do it without using a field, and just using property.
Is it possible?

Comment: no you can't. doesn't make much sense for it to be a property anywayz

Comment: Check the value? Yes. Set it only...set it where if you don't have a field?!

Comment: That `set`can be done like `set { num = value > 0 && value < 100 ? value : num; }`

Comment: there always will be a field.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, why there always will be a field? I can write just get; set; in the property, but I want to check the value

Comment: @Dvir the compiler will generate one for you.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear: *btw; it's not that the property won't be set to that value,* **it's just a different way to look at your question.**

You can use attributes, but you'll need a way to validate them. For instance; the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
[Range(0,100, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public int Num {get; set;}
```

So, this is typically used in MVC or EF like applications where the attributes are being checked by that particular framework.

There is some more info about that subject here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668215(v=vs.110).aspx

It can also work in MVVM WPF applications, but again, you'll need a framework for that.

*btw; it's not that the property won't be set to that value, it's just a different way to look at your question.*

So if your use case is actually how to restrict and easily apply some business rules on a view or data-model, this is an accepted method. If you keep it to your original question `can I do a conditional set without an if and a field?`, the answer is no.

Some more attributes can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: She/He probably couldn't find the library and just down-voted... It happens frequently, there's nothing wrong about your answer.

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes: thank you, I always hope people leave comments on a down-vote so the answer can be improved or better explained.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no. You may want to see this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c) to know why.

> Fields are ordinary member variables or member instances of a class. Properties are an abstraction to get and set their values.

by doing the first block, you just break shorthand that already defined in C# and if you want to implement that idea, I think @Stefan proposed a good one.

Comment: Why, you can just store the value in an external/static dictionary WeakRef(this) -> value.

Comment: @Vlad Why would you want to involve a static dictionary just to avoid having a field on the class?

Comment: @JLRishe: Well, because that's a question we are discussing here :) Besides, WPF does this for dependency properties: most of them have default values, so this allows to reduce memory consumption drastically.