# Assigning private field of object in another class using list of same object c#

Tags: c#

I have two classes, one `ExampleClass` and one `ExampleClassManager`, which contains a list of `ExampleClass`.

`ExampleClass` has a private `_id` field, which I want to set in the `ExampleClassManager` class. Is this possible?

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    //Fields
    private string _id; //Should be set in ExampleClassManager
}


public class ExampleClassManager
{
    //Fields
    List<ExampleClass> exampleClassList = new List<ExampleClass>();  
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the constructor for exampleClass to initialize iD? That way you can pass the id on creation of the class being added to the list.

Comment: If your manager class is used to create the child classes, you can pass the id in the constructor of the child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're several possible options.

1. Make it public (not recommended, because it's bad)
2. Create a public property for access
3. Create a public method to set the value (basically the same as second option)
4. Do it with reflection

I would prefer the second option, because I think it's the cleanes way. When you have no chance to change the modifier you will have to use the fourth option.

Comment: Public fields are not recommended by Microsoft. Your option 2 is the definitely the cleanest approach. Perhaps all OP needs is an auto property `public string iD { get; set;}`.

Comment: Another one would be internal if it is within the same project or an explicit interface implementation.

Comment: What about a constructor?  public fields are an awful idea by the way

Comment: Thanx guys! Will try reflection!

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use properties.

[msdn doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

[answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Example 1: (like Kevin Cook says) ExampleClass takes the `id` in the constructor and then `id` can't be changed:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public class ExampleClass(string id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    //Fields
    private readonly string _id; //note the use of **readonly**
    public string Id { get {return _id; } } //So ExampleClassManager can see the id
}
```

usage:

```
var actualObject = new ExampleClass("abc123");
string myObjectId = actualObject.Id // This should be what was passed in... "abc123"
```

I could give a code example to show how to change the `id` via a property but I've yet to see a case where you'd want an object *identifier* to change once it has been created. There would easily be other fields that you may want to change but that is a different question.