# meaning of typing {set; get;} on a value - C#

Tags: c#

> i'm learning C# and i can't understand what is the difference:

a) `public int value { get; set; }`

b) `public int value`

> i think it have more sense

`public int value { get {return "data:"+somevalue;}}`

Comment: See [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c). That can help you. Because it's a same question.

Comment: Your "I think it have more sense" code actually makes no sense: you said the property is `int` and then you return a string - it's not possible

Comment: Public members of a class should use PascalCase, not camelCase. Typically we do not make fields public; if you want to expose data publicly, use properties but also bear in mind that properties should not return arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is property and another is a field. Equivalent of property in Java is get, set method.
So, in nutshell, "**public int value**" create a field/attribute in your class. Whereas "**public int value { get; set; }**" will create a private field/attribute and two public methods to get(read) and set(write) that field/attribute in class. So, it gives safer way to access your field/attribute.