# What is the correct way to get the user Id to services?

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API controller with an action method that allows users to update their account.

I have a DTO that I bind to the action method. For security reasons, I do not want to get the UserId from the POST, so the DTO that I bind to the action method does not have the UserId property. Instead, it just has the properties that the user is allowed to update:

```
public class UpdateAccountRequest 
{
    public required string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public required string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I then have another DTO that inherits from this Request DTO where I add the UserId:

```
public class UpdateAccountWithUserIdRequest : UpdateAccountRequest  
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Make sure it is only set by the controller and not accepted as a parameter from the client.
    /// Do _NOT_ include in the JavaScript client.
    /// </summary>
    public required int UserId { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

I do not want to access HTTP context from within my services, so in the controller's action method, I create the `UpdateAccountWithUserIdRequest` object by copying the values from the bound `UpdateAccountRequest` and using the `ClaimsPrincipal` to get the `UserId`.

This approach works, but it feels like a hack:

- I need to create a derived class that has the `UserId`
- Make sure that I bind the correct DTO to the action method and set the values manually.

Is there a different approach that I can take to simplify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be handled by your API's security. The client should have no awareness of the User ID, yet it should be provided in an API message credential, eg a signed access token or an encrypted HTTP-only cookie.

As a best practice, User IDs (and other secure values) should never be sent in unprotected request payloads, URL path segments or HTTP headers, where a malicious party might be able to alter them.

Your API should use an [authorization filter](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.cs) of some kind that produces a claims principal containing the User ID and other secure values. Claims should then be [injectable into the API logic](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/logic/services/CompanyService.cs) and used for authorization. In this manner you never need to create duplicate objects.

Answer (score 1):

To securely pass the `UserId` from your controller to your services without including it in your DTO, you can use a service layer that accepts a command object including the `UserId`.

```
// DTO doesn't include UserId
public class UpdateAccountRequest 
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// Internal command includes UserId
public class UpdateAccountCommand 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// Service layer interface
public interface IAccountService 
{
    Task UpdateAccountAsync(UpdateAccountCommand command);
}

// Service layer implementation
public class AccountService : IAccountService 
{
    public async Task UpdateAccountAsync(UpdateAccountCommand command) 
    {
        // Use command.UserId and other properties to update the account
    }
}

// Controller
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService) 
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    [HttpPut("update")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAccount([FromBody] UpdateAccountRequest request) 
    {
        // Retrieve UserId from ClaimsPrincipal
        var userIdClaim = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        if (userIdClaim == null || !int.TryParse(userIdClaim, out var userId))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        // Create command and map DTO to it
        var command = new UpdateAccountCommand 
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Email = request.Email,
            Password = request.Password
        };

        // Pass command to service layer
        await _accountService.UpdateAccountAsync(command);

        ...
    }
}
```

The separation of concerns here is a good practice that can make your code clearer and more secure.
[CQRS pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs)

Answer (score -1):

I think you could delete the `UpdateAccountWithUserIdRequest` DTO and custom the UserId {get;set} like following to make it cannot be set by any other values.  (Inject httpcontext to access the userclaims)

```
    public class UpdateAccountRequest
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UpdateAccountRequest(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public required int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.UserId;
            }
            set
            {
                var claimsid= _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.userid; //get your user id from claim

                if (claimsid != null )
                {
                    this.UserId = claimsid;
                }
                else {
                    this.UserId = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public required string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public required string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

The meaning of {get;set;} https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096967/20240963