# Updating several properties when another property changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

In my model class, I have several lists and other properties. One of these properties is called `CurrentIteration` and constantly gets updated. When this gets updated, I want other properties to update themselves to the element of a corresponding list that is the index of `CurrentIteration`. I thought all's I needed to include was an `OnPropertyChanged` event for the properties I want to update in the setter of `CurrentIteration`. However, they don't seem to be getting called.

```
public class VehicleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<double> _nowTime = new List<double>();
    public List<double> NowTime
    {
        get { return this._nowTime; }
        set { this._nowTime = value; OnPropertyChanged("Nowtime"); }
    }

    private List<double> _VehLat = new List<double>();
    public List<double> VehLat
    {
        get { return this._VehLat; }
        set { this._VehLat = value; OnPropertyChanged("VehLat"); }
    }

    private List<double> _VehLong = new List<double>();
    public List<double> VehLong
    {
        get { return _VehLong; }
        set { _VehLong = value; OnPropertyChanged("VehLong"); }
    }

    //non-list properties
    private int _currentIteration;
    public int CurrentIteration //used to hold current index of the list of data fields
    {
        get { return _currentIteration; }
        set
        {
            _currentIteration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIteration");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLat");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLong");
        }
    }

    private double _currentVehLat;
    public double CurrentVehLat
    {
        get { return _currentVehLat; }
        set { _currentVehLat = VehLat[CurrentIteration]; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLat"); }
    }

    private double _currentVehLong;
    public double CurrentVehLong
    {
        get { return _currentVehLong; }
        set { _currentVehLong = VehLong[CurrentIteration]; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLong"); }
    }

    public void SetData(int i)
    {
        CurrentIteration = i;
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

`CurrentIteration` DOES get updated properly, but the rest do not. The setters get skipped over completely. I'm almost positive it's something simple and my understanding of the setters in this case is wrong, but I'm not sure what it is exactly.

Edit: Here's an example of one of the bindings in XAML:

```
Text="{Binding Path=CurrentVehLong,
               Mode=TwoWay,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind to show how is the databinding in xaml, for those non updating properties? - Thank you

Comment: Sure, added it to the end of the post.

Comment: One option is to simply replace `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLat"); OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLong");` in the `CurrentIteration` setter with calls to the other setters (which will call their own OnPropertyChanged): `CurrentVehLat = double.MaxValue;`, `CurrentVehLong = double.MinValue;` (the values don't matter, you don't ever read `value` in those setters). In this way any time CurrentIteration is assigned, his setter calls the other property's setters which grab the updated `CurrentIteration` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising the property change notification just says "These properties have changed, re-query their values". Meaning it calls the `get` accessor method.

It looks like you are expecting it to call the `set` method, which is not going to happen because you are not setting the value.

Try removing the backing property and just access the array value directly, like this :

```
public double CurrentVehLong
{
    get { return VehLong[CurrentIteration];; }
    set 
    { 
        VehLong[CurrentIteration] = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLong"); 
    }
}
```

Now when you call `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentVehLong")`, it will re-query the `get` accessor for this property, and update the value based on the `CurrentIteration`. I also altered the `set` method so it would make more sense, and you'd be able to use it to set the value if that's what you want to do elsewhere.

Comment: Works great! I think my understanding with these is a little shallow, I was under the impression I always needed a backing value. What exactly is the point of them then? (If it's a long answer no worries).

Comment: @pfinferno Its just a way to store the data for internal access so you don't have to go through the regular get/set accessor methods. The most common reason to do it is to avoid any kind of infinite loops, such as [this answer shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3272900/302677) shows. You could also use auto-properties such as `{ get; set; }` which will cause the compiler to generate the backing field for your internally, although in the case of WPF you typically want the PropertyChange notification in the setter, so write it out yourself.