# Should a property be converted to one with a backing field when there's logic?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If I have a class with a property that has built-in logic for example:

```
class myModelClass
{
    public List<SummaryModel> Coupons {get;set;}

    public decimal AlaCarteTotal
    {
        get
        {
            if (Coupons != null)
            {
                if (!Coupons.Any(x => x.GromotionApplied))
                {
                    return Coupons.Sum(x => x.DefaultPrice);
                }

                return Coupons.Sum(x => x.GromotionApplied ? x.GromoPrice : x.DefaultPrice);
            }

            return default(decimal);
        }
    }
}
```

...would it be better to convert **Coupons** to have a backing field such as here:

```
class myModelClass
{
    public List<SummaryModel> Coupons 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return _Coupons; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            _Coupons = value; 
        } 
    }

    public decimal AlaCarteTotal
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Coupons != null)
            {
                if (!_Coupons.Any(x => x.GromotionApplied))
                {
                    return _Coupons.Sum(x => x.DefaultPrice);
                }

                return _Coupons.Sum(x => x.GromotionApplied ? x.GromoPrice : x.DefaultPrice);
            }

            return default(decimal);
        }
    }
}
```

**More generally, when a model class contains some kind of getter logic, should the property be converted to one with a backing field?**

Comment: I'm confused... your `Coupons` property does not have any logic. So why would you want to give it a backing field? `AlaCarteTotal` is the property with the logic, but it does not need a backing field.... Some may say that it is better style to turn `AlaCarteTotal` into a method instead of a property...

Comment: Think that this ```List<SummaryModel> Coupons {get;set;}``` will have backed field anyway (if you will not do this, compiler will do)

Comment: Maybe off topic, but seeing as AlaCarteTotal needs Coupons to calculate it's total (or check for existence of any), I'd pass Coupons in as a parameter and change it from a property to a method, and remove the need for a separate coupons property altogether.

Comment: I believe this question is just about seeking for 'best practices'. Backing field as described would have no added value, thus I'd not add them just for sake of having them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general recommendation.

It sometime happens that you use some local variables in code and by time you realize you need more complex workflow for setting and obtaining that value.

In case you already have your field as property with (even generic) setter and getter you have your life easier because you just edit your get and set without touching rest of code.

**In short:** Keep it without backing field until you will have purpose for it. `.NET` creates it in background anyway but in case you don't need them for your logic your code will be shorter, more brief.

This one could explain it even more: [Properties backing field - What is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272889/properties-backing-field-what-is-it-good-for)